# SIGPIPE handling by sigwait

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I am trying to implement a graceful shutdown of a process when its output is being piped to another process. I am testing the code bellow by piping its output: `./a.out | less` and pressing `q` when a prompt appears. Instead of expected completion of `sigwait()` I see invocation of signal handler instead (it is added here just to show what is going on).

```
#include <csignal>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <signal.h>

int handlerSig {0};

void signalHandler(int s)
{
    handlerSig = s;
    std::cerr << "handlerSig: "  << handlerSig << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        std::signal(i, signalHandler);
    }

    bool run {true};
    std::thread thread {[&]
        {
            while (run)
            {
                std::cout << "ping" << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds {500});        
            }
        }};

    sigset_t waitSet;
    sigemptyset(&waitSet);
    sigaddset(&waitSet, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&waitSet, SIGPIPE);
    sigaddset(&waitSet, SIGTERM);

    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &waitSet, nullptr);

    int waitSig {0};
    sigwait(&waitSet, &waitSig);
    run = false;
    thread.join();

    std::cerr << "waitSig: "  << waitSig << std::endl;
}
```

I get consistent results on WSL2 and CentOS machine and I would prefer to focus on solving this problem there. When running under WSL1, neither SIGINT nor SIGTERM cause completion of `sigwait()` unless I remove `pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK...)`, but that seems to contradict my understanding how `sigwait()` is supposed to be used.

Comment: `std::cerr << ...` in a signal handler is unsafe. You can only safely make async-signal-safe calls from within a signal handler, and using `std::cerr` and similar is not async-signal-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to contrive some other way of noticing that the write failed, for example, ignoring SIGPIPE but setting `std::cout.exceptions(ios::badbit)`, or handling the signal within your writing thread.

Importantly, that SIGPIPE will *always* be generated for your writing thread, your `sigwait()`ing thread notwithstanding.  Certain signals arising from a thread's activity are *generated exclusively for that thread*, meaning they'll be delivered to or accepted by that thread only.  ([POSIX.1-2008 *System Interfaces* 2.4.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04))  Typically, "naturally occurring" SIGPIPEs, SIGFPEs, and SIGSEGVs work like this.

Comment: Thank you - second paragraph explains my results. For my purpose I might just forward that signal to main thread. I am adding example in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of forwarding SIGPIPE to the main thread - probably sufficient in my case:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <signal.h>

pthread_t mainThread {pthread_self()};

void forwardSig(int sig)
{
    if (not pthread_equal(pthread_self(), mainThread))
    {
        pthread_kill(mainThread, sig);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction newAction {};
    sigemptyset(&newAction.sa_mask);
    newAction.sa_handler = forwardSig;
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &newAction, nullptr);

    bool run {true};
    std::thread thread {[&]
        {
            while (run)
            {
                std::cout << "ping" << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds {500});        
            }
        }};

    sigset_t waitSet;
    sigemptyset(&waitSet);
    sigaddset(&waitSet, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&waitSet, SIGPIPE);
    sigaddset(&waitSet, SIGTERM);

    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &waitSet, nullptr);

    int waitSig {0};
    sigwait(&waitSet, &waitSig);
    run = false;
    thread.join();

    std::cerr << "waitSig: "  << waitSig << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd take this cautiously: you want `sigaction` not `signal` (search here on SO for why), you want `pthread_equal` not equality operators, and you still have unblocked signals in your worker thread that you ought to consider.  (The spec doesn't prioritize block+`sigwait` over normal handling — what if a terminal's Ctrl-C SIGINT is delivered to the worker and not the main thread?)

Comment: @pilcrow as suggested - I have incorporated `sigaction` and `pthread_equal` into my code above. What would cause terminal signal to be sent to a child thread instead of the main thread - is that defined anywhere? I am not considering purposely sending signals to a child thread in this example.